# Xamarin: Entry with Icon: Text overlapping

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

So I have this xaml file on my end, what I want is that I want the entry's text not to be behind/overlap with the icon itself.

In order to achieve the icon on the right, I had two columns: One for the entry and one for the icon

I set the  `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` of the entry and set the icon `HorizontalOptions="End"` but the text of the entry was behind my icon, how do I prevent this? If more info is needed, do not hesitate to ask me so. Thanks!

EDIT1: Here's the Code

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Entry Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsPassword="True"/>
   <Image Source="eye.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Add your code here which you have tried.

Comment: I couldnt understand what you exactly mean but I guess that you try to overlap icon over entry. Have you tried Absolutelayout for this?

Comment: @batmaci I have an entry, and an icon. I want to overlap the icon with the entry, but not exactly the content of the entry. Like what I've posted along with the image, you can see that the content of the entry was behind the icon itself, and I do not want that to happen. Does entry have padding?

Comment: @ZiyadGodil Updated my post.

Comment: ok you are trying to do something like classic "show password" entry, i believe.

Comment: have you tried absolutelayout or relativelayout? if not I will post some code for you

Comment: you set width auto of grid for image or you can do using stack layout see my answer.

Comment: @batmaci I've tried a lot of things, from what I've remembered I did try absolutelayout, but I forgot how I did it though.

Comment: @ZiyadGodil I'll try it tomorrow, I do not have my machine right now.. Thanks..

Comment: @batmaci Yes, I am trying to do a show password entry. Sorry for not posting it along with the post

Answer (score 5):

Change your grid width * to Auto

```
<Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Entry Grid.Column="0" IsPassword="True"/>
       <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="eye.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" />
    </Grid>
```

## OR

Try stack layout instead of grid

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
    <Entry IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Image Source="eye.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: While this works, so in order for the image to have a border I added a boxview below it, however, its result when the image is clicked, it flickers. The reason why I wanted the entry (to kinda overlap the image) so that it would inherit the border of the entry.

Comment: Didn't get you. Are you mean image flicker when you clicked

Comment: Yes, it does flicker, a border below the image flickers when it is being clicked.

Comment: Are you put any animation effect on image when click?

Comment: Well, not really an animation but the image changes to something else.

Comment: are you using grid or StackLayout?

Comment: I think are you check in android so its default bottom border you should remove bottom border try this https://gist.github.com/dkudelko/42f2d5bc1c8b3aba1d3d

Comment: Yes, grid, and that's what I am thinking about. If I want to really overlap it without going through heavy custom renderer for tap recognizer for image and text change of the password, I should just implement a custom renderer for each platform by removing their borders and just implement a boxview as a hack. Well. I will try it tomorrow. I'll give you a heads up if I managed to do so.

Comment: I have tried it, but it still does flicker, I am now using a StackLayout when doing the show/hide password effect.

Comment: I fixed it by setting height/width request

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Entry Grid.Column="0" IsPassword="True"/>
   <Image Source="eye.png" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did:

Cross-platform xaml file:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Spacing="0">
     <Entry  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsPassword="True"/>
     <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" 
                           HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           HeightRequest="20"
                           WidthRequest="20">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MaskCommand}"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
<StackLayout>
```

Android Renderer:

```
Control?.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

I'll update this after I have tried it on iOS and UWP.